# Endomorphisms and almost all graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Is it known what fraction (almost all?) of graphs have a trivial endomorphism monoid?  I can't seem to find any reference to the question.  Maybe it's related to the question: what fraction of graphs have chromatic number equal to their clique number?

Answer (score 12):

The book "Graph Homomorphisms" contains an elegant proof that a random graph admits only the identity endomorphism.

The term to search on is "rigid graph". (This has two different meanings but they are easy to distinguish.)

Comment: Is this the book? Graphs and Homomorphisms http://www.amazon.com/Graphs-Homomorphisms-Lecture-Mathematics-Applications/dp/0198528175/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1418579781&sr=8-1&keywords=Graph+Homomorphisms&pebp=1418579828333

Comment: Yes, that's it. I also think that if you google a bit you might find some notes online giving the proof.